# Pipelines dinamicos en Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Buenas, estoy empezando con Jenkins y tengo una duda. Tengo una serie de Jobs en Jenkins (p.e. J1, J2, J3, J4 y J5).

Y el primero me genera un archivo .txt (que podría modificarse a cualquier tipo de archivo) con los siguientes jobs a ejecutar en el orden que sea. Es decir, algunas veces se ejecutara:
J2, J3, J4 y J5

Pero podría darse otros casos:

J2, J4 y J5.

J3 y J5.
[...]

Sabeis si hay algun plugin que me pueda ayudar? O si se puede crear un Pipeline a través de código?

Un saludo y gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

con los pipelines de Jenkins podes generar código con condiciones

Ej:

```
Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)

when {
    // A or B
    expression { return A || B }
}
steps {
    /* step */
}
```

Te dejo el link de donde saque la información

https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/01/19/converting-conditional-to-pipeline/

Answer (score 0):

Si tu J1 determina que jobs se van a ejecutar, dentro de tu pipeline puedes construir los demas jobs
p. e.

```
pipeline {
  environment{
    J2 = false
    J3 = false
    J4 = false
    ......
  }
  stages{
    stage("determinador"){
    ... pasos para determinar que jobs se ejecutaran, cambiar J# a true segun sea el caso
  }
  stage("run jobs"){
    steps{
      script{
        if(J2) {
          job build: "path/J2", params: <opcional>, wait: false
        }
        if(J3) {
          job build: "path/J3", params: <opcional>, wait: false
        }
        if(J4) {
          job build: "path/J4", params: <opcional>, wait: false
        }
        ...
      }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

aqui esta la documentacion https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/

y aqui un ejemplo con parametros https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/221400287-How-to-pass-parameter-to-downstream-job-in-Pipeline-job-